# Unable to access token using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch token from an API and use that token to access more data from the API. When I try to apply that API on Postman, it works fine. So the API is correct. But when I try to get it through code, I get undefined as response. So I am doing something wrong in my code.

```
useEffect(() => {
axios.get('https:/myURL/LoginService/login?login=admin&password=password', { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"})
    .then((response) => {sessionStorage.setItem("authToken", response["log.loginResponse"]["log.return"]);
});
});
```

Is this the correct way of accessing the token ?

Postman response data looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:loginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://myURL/groupService/" xmlns:ns3="http://myURL/loginService/" xmlns:ns4="http://myURL/userService/">
    <ns3:return>authKey</ns3:return>
</ns3:loginResponse>
```

Comment: This is because when the component is mounted `useEffect` is immediately fired and your `API` call takes some time to retrieve data. While at the time of mounting the data is undefined that's why you are getting undefined in return

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it ? Or this is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log your response
I think your data is in

```
//not response but response.data["log.loginResponse"]
.then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Thank you :) Do you this this is efficient way of accessing it ?

Comment: I don't know, but I prefer to create a function outside the useEffect and catch the error 

function getToken (){
  axios.get('https:/myURL/LoginService/login?login=admin&password=password', { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"})
    .then((response) => {sessionStorage.setItem("authToken", response.data["log.loginResponse"]["log.return"]);
   .catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
});
}
useEffect(() => {
 getToken ();
},[])

Comment: @user2128 give me points please :) , two things you can  see, first look the async function with **.catch()** or async await and second in useEffect look the dependencie if you don't pass any dependecy like useEffect(() => {}) it's re-render all the time like componentWillUpdate() but if you want one call you need empty array like useEffect(() => { },[])  with empty array is like componentDidMount()